# RedisStore - TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

When I run the app I get that message.
I am trying to follow the instructions described [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport.socket.io)

This is a portion of my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express); 
var redisStore = new RedisStore(); // setup redis
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var routes  = require('./routes')
```

Comment: Something is undefined, that is explicitly calling `.prototype...`. Double-check all the modules are installed, and then search your code for "prototype" (because likely these other packages aren't having this problem...)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**If you want to use Express 4.x**

change from

```
var express = require('express');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
```

to

```
var session = require('express-session')
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

Also remember to install *express-session*:

```
npm install express-session --save
```

**If you plan to use Express 3.x**, pick compatible version 1.4.7 of **connect-redis** to avoid the error.

```
 npm install connect-redis@1.4.7 --save
```

To get more information about **migrating Express 3 to version 4**:

- http://blog.avrora.io/2014/05/13/migration-from-express-3-x-to-4-0/
- https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis#connect-redis

Comment: For anybody working through 'Node.js The Right Way' by Jim R. Wilson and having issues getting server.js running in Chapter 8, then this will help you, as it helped me! :)